# Why ElassticSearch unavailable after restart, some shard unassigned?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, centos

I have a elasticsearch service running on one node.  After I restart the ES. Some shard remain unassigned for a few minute.

The whole step is like below:

1. I load a lot data into my Elasticsearch.
2. I kill my elasticsearch process
3. After restart, the elasticsearch become red. Some Shard remain un-assigned.

Something I noticed is that. Before I kill the elasticsearch, I checked the shard, it is like this

```
[sflow@ES01 bin]$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'
index             shard prirep state      docs store ip            node 
sflow_51452355200 2     p      STARTED 5997062 2.8gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 1     p      STARTED 6000474 2.9gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 4     p      STARTED 5997701 3.1gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 3     p      STARTED 5999565   3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 0     p      STARTED 5999198 2.8gb 10.79.148.184 ES01
```

The size of each shard is not balanced.

After I restart, the shard will like below for a while

```
[sflow@ES01 bin]$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'
index             shard prirep state        docs store ip            node 
sflow_51452355200 4     p      INITIALIZING            10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 2     p      INITIALIZING            10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 3     p      UNASSIGNED                                 
sflow_51452355200 1     p      INITIALIZING            10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 0     p      INITIALIZING            10.79.148.184 ES01
```

Then after a few min， the shard become below

```
[sflow@ES01 bin]$ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v'
index             shard prirep state      docs store ip            node 
sflow_51452355200 4     p      STARTED 5997701 2.3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 2     p      STARTED 5997062 2.3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 3     p      STARTED 5999565 2.3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 1     p      STARTED 6000474 2.3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01 
sflow_51452355200 0     p      STARTED 5999198 2.3gb 10.79.148.184 ES01
```

**It seems data in the index is re-balanced. But I thought the where the data should be located is decided during the index time by the routing method. Why the data got re-balanced after I restart the index?**

Comment: As far as I can see, this is a perfectly valid restart and recovery process. Not sure what you would expect to be different. Re-balancing can only occur if you have multiple nodes, which you don't. What you're experiencing is simply the re-initialization process of shards during startup.

Comment: Hi as I know the data should be routed to specified shard at index time. Once it is done, it is done. it belongs to a specified shard. But in the above test, some data obviously moved from shard to shard. Because the size of shard is changing after the index is done. Why is that?

Comment: The size of the shard is not only linked to the number of documents, but many other things as well, like the number of "deleted" documents, the doc values, and many other Lucene files that live under the hood. Lucene does some housekeeping during startup and I wouldn't worry to much about that.

Comment: Hi Val, thanks very much for the explain. I`m just curious about this. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baed on Val comment.

The size of the shard is not only linked to the number of documents, but many other things as well, like the number of "deleted" documents, the doc values, and many other Lucene files that live under the hood. Lucene does some housekeeping during startup

So it is an normal startup process

Answer (score 1):

By default there are `5 primary shards` and `one replica shard` for every index you create. If you have only one instance/ one node of elastic search running, all `primary shards` will be assigned to that node and remaining `replica shards` will be in `unassigned` state. You can overcome this by running another instance/node.

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cluster_health.html):

> unassigned_shards are shards that exist in the cluster state, but cannot be found in the cluster itself. A common source of unassigned shards are unassigned replicas. For example, an index with five shards and one replica will have five unassigned replicas in a single-node cluster.

Comment: Note that there are no replica shards in his example, only primary ones and the unassigned shard is a primary.

Comment: Yes, @Val is right. I do not use replica shard in my case. Only 5 primary shard.  Actually I hit this issue several times. Every time the shard with number 2 will hit issue. But normally it will became ok after 5~6 minutes

Comment: @KramerLi can you confirm that you get a green cluster eventually (i.e. after a few minutes)? If yes, then there is no issue.

Comment: Hi @Val. I updated my question. Can you have look please

Comment: @Richa  thanks still. Can you check my question again. I updated some new finding